# Site with (full?) copy of stackexchange including translation

Tags: discussion, scraper-sites

I came across that site/page

[antwortenhier.me](https://antwortenhier.me/q/shiv-im-mi-yodeya-32293968475)

This is exactly a question in stackexchange, but translated to german (using google?):

[judaism.stackexchange.com](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2365/shivim-mi-yodeya)

I came originally on this site "antwortenhier.me" searching for my name and some mathematical, and then religious terms. Is this site already known? I might also note, that the "antwortenhier.me" - links came as first founds in the google-search-list.

Comment: @Brahadeesh - thanks, just contacted the SE-team via their contact-form.

Comment: Please before closing: isn't it a useful information to see the site's url in the "scrapers"- list-of-cases question? (or: to have a "big-list" of such url's?)

Comment: there's another asktoworld